# Travel sites that offer multiple period search

Tags: online-resources, tickets

I am looking for a travel website that allows me to look at current prices to travel from point A to B within the next "x" months? Any sites do this?

Answer (score 3):

Try [Adioso](http://adioso.com/).  You can search "anytime" or specify this month/next month/any calendar month.  This works only one month at a time, mind you, but it's still faster than trying to do this with a normal flight search engine.